# iOS - in-app purchase with content as video - can it be streamed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, video-streaming

I'm currently have got an app on the app store that includes 16 video-lessons each duration about 45 minutes. Videos are included into app archive, so it's about 1.8 GB.
My question is: if i would add 16 in-app purchase with content of that video, would it be possible not just to download the and then play inside the app, but also play it live (as in youTube) or download for offline usage?
Can anybody share experience in this field?

Comment: I recommend not including the iap in the app archive. Somebody who's rooted could then just browse through the app files.

Comment: I would upload the videos onto a private server, perhaps on your LAN, set up an apache server, port forward the address, and then have the application load that video file.

Comment: Or just upload it to YouTube and set the viewer audience  to only those with a link.  Then embed the YouTube video into your app, so they can't view it outside your app (and possibly share that link with the outside world). Hope this helps.

Comment: @coltonon that's a good solution, but if they want to have it offline?

Comment: The YouTube option seems the best, but it would have to exist on a server somewhere to be able to download it.  That's when the apache server would be used.  Or just some kind of free web hosting would also do.  Heck, even a direct download link.  So upload the files somewhere, and when they choose to view offline, the app just downloads the file from the link into the application archive.

Comment: But be aware of my first comment.

Comment: @coltonon Yep, thanks you. Is it possible to download videos from dropbox or google drive? I mean 16 video for one user are about 1.8 GB, so i would get a big bill on the hosting...

Comment: Sure. In your web browser on a PC, download your file.  Then go to your downloads folder in the browser (just press Ctrl+J) and look at the downloaded link. It is going to be really long and completely randomized.  Run that link through goo.gl or something for easiness. Sorry if I wasn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry that was really confusing. Here's step by step.  Upload your file to Dropbox or google drive. Download the file from one of those websites. Press control J. A downloads tab should appear. Find the file you just downloaded. Next to it should be a blue link. Copy that.  I recommend shortening it in bitly or goo.gl.

Comment: Yep, i got that. Thanks a lot. You can post all that as an answer and i would accept it.

Comment: Hi @coltonon . It sounds like a simple solution, but if the user use a web debugger like Charles Proxy, couldnt they  just get the urls and share them? Another question, how can serg_ov add more videos in the dynamically?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.  Honestly I'd have the "pro" users have some credentials registered in an SQL database, hosting the files privately.